# Function doesn't recognize a the color of a pixel on a bitmap

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

I'm recreating something like the python turtle in c#, which has a lot of functions that help the turtle draw lines on a picture. Im trying to do a check if there is a red pixel (Color.Red) two pixels infront of the snake, but it isn't working. The snake doesn't see the color, which it should.
Here is used Code with a bit of explanation:

```
class Turtle
{
    public Bitmap map { get; set; }
    public string dir { get; set; }
    public string startdir { get; set; }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

this is the turtle class with the map it's on, it's position, direction and the amount of times it moved.

```
static Turtle TurtleCreate()
    {
        Turtle turtle = new Turtle();
        Bitmap map = new Bitmap(10, 10);
        turtle.map = map;
        turtle.x = 0;
        turtle.y = 0;
        turtle.dir = "Down";
        turtle.startdir = "Down";
        turtle.age = 0;
        return turtle;
    }
```

This is the function that is used for creating a new Turtle with just one easy line of code. It sets all of the variables in the turtle class.

```
static Turtle TurtleTurnLeft(Turtle turtle)
    {
        switch (turtle.dir)
        {
            case "Down":
                turtle.dir = "Right";
                break;
            case "Right":
                turtle.dir = "Up";
                break;
            case "Up":
                turtle.dir = "Left";
                break;
            case "Left":
                turtle.dir = "Down";
                break;
            case "RD":
                turtle.dir = "UR";
                break;
            case "DL":
                turtle.dir = "RD";
                break;
            case "LU":
                turtle.dir = "DL";
                break;
            case "UR":
                turtle.dir = "LU";
                break;
        }
        return turtle;
    }
```

this is the function that is used to turn the turtle to the left. It just checks the current direction (UR = Up-Right) and sets it to its new direction, then returns it.

```
static Turtle TurtleMove(Turtle turtle)
    {
        turtle.y = Math.Clamp(turtle.y, 0, turtle.map.Height - 1);
        turtle.x = Math.Clamp(turtle.x, 0, turtle.map.Width - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(turtle.x + ", " + turtle.y);
        try
        {
            turtle.map.SetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y, Color.Red);
        }
        catch { }
        switch (turtle.dir)
        {
            case "Down":
                turtle.y++;
                break;
            case "Left":
                turtle.x--;
                break;
            case "Up":
                turtle.y--;
                break;
            case "Right":
                turtle.x++;
                break;
            case "RD":
                turtle.x++;
                turtle.y++;
                break;
            case "DL":
                turtle.y++;
                turtle.x--;
                break;
            case "LU":
                turtle.x--;
                turtle.y--;
                break;
            case "UR":
                turtle.y--;
                turtle.x++;
                break;
        }
        turtle.age++;
        turtle.map.Save(@"C:\Users\1ru\Desktop\Ich\Programming\Gen " + turtle.age + ".jpg");
        return turtle;
    }
```

this is the moving function. Again it checks the direction, sets the new position and colors the last position red (Color.Red). Then it sets the age up by on and puts this "Generation" into the folder I assigned.

```
static bool TurtleWall(Turtle turtle)
    {
        bool Wall = false;
        switch (turtle.dir)
        {
            case "Down":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y + 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Left":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - 1, turtle.y);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Up":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y - 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "Right":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + 1, turtle.y);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "RD":
                turtle.x++;
                 try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + 1, turtle.y + 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "DL":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - 1, turtle.y + 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "LU":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - 1, turtle.y - 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
            case "UR":
                try
                {
                    turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + 1, turtle.y - 1);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Wall = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return Wall;
    }
```

this is the function that checks if there is a Wall infront of the turtle. It checks the direction and then tries to get the pixel and if it can't, it assumes there is a "wall" there. (the border of the image)

```
static bool TurtleWall(Turtle turtle, Color color, int amount)
    {
        bool Wall = false;
        switch (turtle.dir)
        {
            case "Down":
                try 
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y + amount) == color)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Yes");
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "Left":
                try
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - amount, turtle.y) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "Up":
                try 
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y - amount) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "Right":
                try 
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + amount, turtle.y) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "RD":
                turtle.x++;
                try
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + amount, turtle.y + amount) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "DL":
                try
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - amount, turtle.y + amount) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "LU":
                try
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x - amount, turtle.y - amount) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
            case "UR":
                try
                {
                    if (turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x + amount, turtle.y - amount) == color)
                    {
                        Wall = true;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                break;
        
        return Wall;
    }
```

this is the same function as before, but it has a color and amount parameter. it checks if there is a pixel with the assigned color as many pixels in front of it as the parameter is set to. The Problem is here, it just doesn't recognize the color it's supposed to.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Turtle turtle = TurtleCreate();
        turtle.map.SetPixel(0, 5, Color.Red);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (TurtleWall(turtle) == true || TurtleWall(turtle, Color.Red, 2))
            {
                turtle = TurtleTurnLeft(turtle);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            turtle = TurtleMove(turtle);
        }
    }
```

this is the main function. It creates a new turtle and walks forward everytime you press a key and it's supposed to turn left when there is a wall infront of it or a color 2 pixels in front of it. Like I said the wall works, but the color doesn't. I tried everything.

I'm from Germany and am not good at tiping in English but I would be really Happy if someone read this and tried to help me. Thank you!

Update:
The program recognizes the pixel as Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0]. Is it possible that Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0] isn't the same as Color.Red?

Comment: When comparing a real color from a GetPixel call with a named color do use the [Color.ToArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.toargb?view=net-5.0) function: `if (color == Color.ToArgb(Color.Red))..` - A named color does have extra fields and there fore will not be equal to a simple color struct.. - Of course you also need to avoid color shift in compresed bitmaps like `jpg`s.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't quite get how I am supposed to do it now? turtle.map.GetPixel(turtle.x, turtle.y + amount) == Color.FromArgb(Color.Red) doesn't work

Comment: Not FromArgb but ToArgb ! - For clearer codeuse  a precalculated variable: `Color wallColor = Color.Red.ToArgb();` - This should work. If it doesn't do have a closer look at the numbers in the channels!

Comment: for some reason ToArgb doesn't take a parameter?

Comment: Whoops, you are right, my bad. It is a function to use on the Red itself..

Comment: Ok, i got it. I turned both of them into an int with ToArgb and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: _Is it possible that Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0] isn't the same as Color.Red?_ As I wrote, named/known colors include a few extra fields, including their Name, state and then some and will therefor not be equal. You could try to find more in the [sources](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/CommonUI/System/Drawing/Color@cs/1/Color@cs), but I don't have time atm..